# Help with understanding this proof (I think it's Hensels Lifting?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am reading a proof that shows that if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^k$, where $p$ is a prime > $2$ and $k$ is a positive integer, then it is also a quadratic residue modulo $p^{k+1}$.

Here is the beginning of the proof where I am stuck:

Let $a$ be a quadratic residue mod $p^k$ $(k \ge 1)$

$\implies x^2 = a +bp^k$, for integers a, b

(Here is where I don't understand):

Since $2x$ is not divisble by $p$, there is a solution of linear congruence $2xy \equiv -b \pmod p$, and we have:

$(x+yp^k)^2 = x^2 + 2xyp^k+ y^2p^{2k}= a + (b+2xy)p^k+y^2p^{2k}\equiv a \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

I'm ok with understanding the last line of algebra/modulo arithmetic, but I am having trouble understanding the last line before it:

> Since $2x$ is not divisble by $p$, there is a solution of linear congruence $2xy \equiv -b \pmod p$

I think it might have something to do with Hensel's lifting, but even after a bunch of reading I find that I am not really understanding it.

Could someone help me out with a simple explanation here? I'm a beginner in this area of number theory. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field, the element $2x$ of this field is not zero, hence it has a multiplicative inverse.

Let me elaborate: Let $r$ be an integer that is not a multiple of $p$. We consider the remainder of $nr$ after division by $p$ for all $0\le n<p$. These are all different, because if $nr\equiv n'r\pmod p$, then $(n-n')r$ is divisible by $p$, and since $p$ is prime and does not divide $r$, $n-n'$ has to be divisible by $p$, and the only possibility for that is $n=n'$. But now if the remainders of $nr$ are all distinct numbers from $0$ to $p-1$, then actually each of these numbers has to occur exactly once. This means that for $r\not\equiv0\pmod p$ and $m$ arbitrary there is always an $n$ such that $nr\equiv m\pmod p$.

Not let $r=2x$, $m=-b$, $n=y$.

Comment: Hi Carsten, sorry, I'm taking elementary number theory at the moment, haven't studied fields..is there another way to explain it? Or perhaps a reference to a simple explanation? Thanks!

Comment: So you also have not heard of the rings $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$? Ok, I have added an elementary proof of the needed fact, hth.

Comment: I have heard of Rings, but have not learnt about them yet. To have a guess, is it a way to describe a complete system modulo m? Thanks, I do follow your further explanation - but I guess my question is - how did the author come up with this congruence to use in this proof? It seems to have just come out of nowhere?